# Export .exe details to csv

Tags: command-line

Suppose I want to have the list of all the .exe files running on my system. Can that be done using the command "tasklist"? Also, how do i export all those file names and their details into a csv file?

Answer (score 2):

The following typed into command prompt should do the trick:

```
tasklist /fo csv > txt.csv
```

As result `tasklist` produces the list of `.exe` running on your system, `/fo csv` specifies the output format as a csv file, ">" tells command prompt that you want the output to go to a file instead of to the command prompt window, and `txt.csv` is the name of the file you want the data stored in.

Comment: Thanx!! Do I need to already create a csv file for storage or it would be dynamically created when the command is entered?

Comment: The file should be dynamically created when the command is entered (i.e. you don't have to create a csv file beforehand).

Comment: Thankyou, That was helpful again! Using the above i can pull all the exe's. but is there anyway which shows the status also of those exe's, like "running", "stopped", etc? Is there any other command apart from "tasklist" which would include a separate column to show the status of the each exe file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can modify the tasklist command shown in the answer to only display running commands by adding the following: /fi "status eq running". So the whole command would read: tasklist /fo csv /fi "status eq running" > txt.csv  . I'm not sure if you can display all the .exe with whether they are running or stopped.  Perhaps this page will help you: http://www.computerhope.com/tasklist.htm.

Comment: @V.Jan `/v` (verbose) will include the status (and other things as well) `"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage","Status","User Name","CPU Time","Window Title"`

Comment: Hey, what if I want to extract the list of all the applications running on my system? "Tasklist" provides the list of running Processes. Is there any specific command for getting the running applications?

Comment: @V.Jan applications are just processes

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to `tasklist` that might yield more interesting details.

```
wmic process get * /format:csv > processes.csv
```

To see the same output in a more readable way use `/format:htable > processes.html` and open the created file in your favorite browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PowerShell, then you can type:

`Get-Process | Export-Csv process.csv`

This will get you a lot more information than you probably need such as:

```
Handles, VM, WS, PM, NPM, Path, Company, CPU, FileVersion, ProductVersion, Description, Product, BasePriority, ExitCode, HasExited, ExitTime, Handle, SafeHandle, HandleCount, Id, MachineName, MainWindowHandle, MainWindowTitle, MainModule, MaxWorkingSet, MinWorkingSet, Modules, NonpagedSystemMemorySize, NonpagedSystemMemorySize64, PagedMemorySize, PagedMemorySize64, PagedSystemMemorySize, PagedSystemMemorySize64, PeakPagedMemorySize, PeakPagedMemorySize64, PeakWorkingSet, PeakWorkingSet64, PeakVirtualMemorySize, PeakVirtualMemorySize64, PriorityBoostEnabled, PriorityClass, PrivateMemorySize, PrivateMemorySize64, PrivilegedProcessorTime, ProcessName, ProcessorAffinity, Responding, SessionId, StartInfo, StartTime, SynchronizingObject, Threads, TotalProcessorTime, UserProcessorTime, VirtualMemorySize, VirtualMemorySize64, EnableRaisingEvents, StandardInput, StandardOutput, StandardError, WorkingSet, WorkingSet64, Site, Container
```

Note:  You might need to run PowerShell as administrator to have access to some of the values.